# How to add None values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am reading an Excel file  containing some rows featuring empty fields. How can I fill empty fields with `None`?

```
  projectid     name   reference jurisdiction_doctype  shipping_datedue isthis_a_rush workflow allocated_date
  0   CF805011     Calib  9802476632         Lien Release   03-31-2021           yes    In DR     03-25-2021
  1   CF80501      Calib  9802476632         Lien Release    03-31-2021          yes    In DR     
  2                Calib  9802476632         Lien Release                        yes    In DR     03-25-2021
  3   CF80501yyy   Calib                     Lien Release    03-31-2021          yes    In DR     03-25-2021
  4   CF8050       Calib  9802476632         Lien Release    03-31-2021          yes    In DR     03-25-2021
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect these "empty" values are not actually blank, but contain zero-length strings, `''`. To check this (and replace them with the string `None`), try:

```
df = df.replace([''], [None])
```

(In my testing with pandas version 1.3.2, I had to wrap both `''` and `None` in list brackets to achieve the expected result.)

**EDIT:** effectively the same but more canonical is to represent missing values is to use numpy's `nan` object:

```
import numpy as np
df = df.replace('', np.nan)
```

Comment: psycopg2.errors.InvalidDatetimeFormat: invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "nan"
CONTEXT:  COPY dynamic_models_test34, line 9, column allocated_date: "nan"

Comment: Oh I see, seems like your error is coming from your subsequent step to insert values into a database. How about running this before your database steps: `df = df.replace({np.nan: None})`?

Comment: same error ,,,,,                                                                                          psycopg2.errors.InvalidDatetimeFormat: invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "nan"

Comment: It seems that `np.nan` is persisting in the datetime columns. After filling with `None`, when you `print(df)`, do you see any `NaN`, or do you see all formerly missing values as `None`?

Comment: while print(df) it resulted with None , i need emty colums should store emty in database and null or none as none...